# matching regex pattern for different emails

Tags: java

I want a `regex` pattern which will match different emails like

- anoop.v93@gmail.com
- sairoshan.9999@gmail.com
- anoopv@gmail.com

here is my code please help thanks in advance.

```
Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w)[^@]+@\\S+(\\.[^\\s.]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(text);
if(emailMatcher.find()) {
    html = emailMatcher.replaceAll("$1***@****$2");
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: Use the regex at: http://emailregex.com/, this should work everytime

Comment: Well, does it work?  What help do you need?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: You should really read why ["Can someone help me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: regex pattern which i posted along with my code is not working for emails like anoop.v93@gmail.com

Comment: what is the output expected ?

Comment: regex pattern which i posted along with my code is not working for emails like anoop.v93@gmail.com  @Dawood ibn Kareem

Comment: @Anoop Why not?

Comment: it should match and mask email id from file which contains a long paragraphs as we all know email ids will be in different patterns  regex should match all email id's

Comment: what is "email id" ?

Comment: email id's be like anoop.v93@gmail.com,sairoshan.9999@gmail.com,anoopv@gmail.com @azro

Comment: Yes, your regular expression _does_ match `anoop.v93@gmail.com` - I just tested it.